# momentjs toDate - different output on different clients/browsers

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, momentjs, timezone-offset

I use momentjs to parse a Date String and convert it to a native JavaScript Date:

```js
let dateString = '1980-04-06';
console.log(moment().utcOffset());
console.log(moment(dateString, 'YYYY-MM-DD').toDate());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

The output on client 1(Firefox 62) is

```
120
Date 1980 - 04 - 05 T23: 00: 00.000 Z
```

and the output on client 2(Firefox 52 ESR) is

```
120
Date 1980 - 04 - 05 T22: 00: 00.000 Z
```

Can somebody explain me, why the utcOffset is the same (`new Date().getTimezoneOffset()` prints also `-120` on both clients), but the Date (hour) is different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're checking the *current* UTC offset, not the offset of your 1980 moment instance. My guess is that if you took `moment(dateString, 'YYYY-MM-DD')` and called `utcOffset` on *that*, you'd get different offsets on the different browsers.

I bet what's happening is that the rules for your zone have changed since 1980 (for example, perhaps the timing of the DST has changed, or DST has been added or eliminated, or perhaps the standard offset has even changed). Browsers vary in the degree to which they get historical zone data right, which leads to errors interpreting date strings. I suspect that Firefox fixed their historical zone database for your zone, leading to different behavior in newer versions of the browser.

Comment: +1 this also.  I was writing my answer with the details at the same time, but you are indeed correct here. :)

Answer (score 3):

The offsets you're showing are for the *current* date and time, not for the date provided.  If you change the middle line to log `moment(dateString, 'YYYY-MM-DD').utcOffset()`, you should see that the result in the older Firefox 52 is `60` instead of `120`.

Contributing factors explaining this difference are:

- The daylight saving time rules for your time zone are not the same in 1980 as they are today.  Assuming Vienna (from your user profile), in 1980 the start of DST was at 00:00 on April 6th ([reference here](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/austria/vienna?year=1980)) which is the first Sunday in April.  The current (2018) rule for Vienna is the last Sunday in March, which would be March 25th 2018 ([reference here](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/austria/vienna?year=2018)).
- [ECMAScript 5.1 (section 15.9.1.8)](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.8)  and earlier required browsers to always assume the current DST rule was in effect for all time - even if this was not actually what happened.  This was corrected in [ECMAScript 6 / 2015 (section 20.3.1.8)](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-daylight-saving-time-adjustment) .
- ECMAScript 2015 was implemented in Firefox starting with version 54.  Since you are testing version 52, you are seeing the old behavior.
- Since this particular DST change is right at the stroke of midnight, and it's a spring-forward transition, then, `1980-04-06T00:00` is not valid.  The first moment of that day in that time zone is `1980-04-06T01:00`.  Moment takes care of this for you when you pass a date-only value.  In the current browser (62, not 52), If you call `.format()` on the moment, you should see `1980-04-06T01:00:00+02:00`.  Note that this is time is already in DST, with a UTC+02:00 offset.  Converted to UTC is `1980-04-05T23:00:00Z`, thus aligning with the correct data as seen in your examples.

Long story short, there are many reasons to use up-to-date browsers.  This is one of them.

Comment: Also, I could be mistaken, but I don't believe Firefox 52 is supported any longer - even the ESR version.

Comment: There are also differences on when browsers do the adjustment. Some seem to do it on the stroke of the hour, others the millisecond afterward.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation. it helped me a lot to understand the problems cause.